# Use SonarQube without SCM engine

Tags: c#, version-control, sonarqube, controls, version

I'm C# developer and We planning to use SonarQube.

Is there to use sonarQube without any version control tool such as can SonarQube read source folder directly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can run using the command-line (which you can probably schedule I guess). It involves running the plugin for MSBuild (MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe), pass it some arguments and then you do your normal build using MSBuild command-line and then upload your results to SQ.

Source control is not a requirement. All is explained in this excellent document, pay particular attention to the analysis from command line sections.

http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/sq-setup-guide-for-dotnet-users.html

Comment: Thanks a lot most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Simply turn off the SCM Sensor at either the Global or Project level: **Administration > General > SCM > Disable the SCM Sensor** set to `true`